# Dutch-born, Belgian nationality, living in South Africa, can I get Dutch citizenship?

Tags: citizenship

I was born in Nijmegen on 23.03.1943.
My mother before her marriage was Dutch and was born in Meppel.
She married my father who had Belgian nationality at the time of their marriage and of my birth, so I acquired Belgian nationality involuntarily.
Both parents late in life became Dutch citizens in while living in South Africa where I still live and still have my Belgian nationality.
I would like to acquire Dutch citizenship as this is where I was born and I speak the language fluently.
Is it possible for me to obtain my Dutch nationality?

Comment: Did your mother still have Dutch citizenship when you were born?

Comment: @mkennedy this may be irrelevant.  Under Article 1 of the [1892 law](https://pvmarkus.home.xs4all.nl/wet.htm) (in effect at the time), the mother's nationality was relevant only for children born out of wedlock who were not formally acknowledged by the father.  There are some exceptions in Article 2, however, that may apply (for example if the maternal grandmother was living in the Netherlands when the mother was born, if I read it correctly).

Comment: @phoog I was looking at the "latent citizenship" section on Wikipedia which prompted the question, but admittedly was having a hard time tracing through the various laws and what might apply.

Comment: @mkennedy ah yes, I'd forgotten about that.  I was only familiar with the option procedure for ex-Dutch citizens.  No time to look more into that at the moment but I will do so in the next day or two.