# Am I eligible for a Dutch passport?

Tags: passport

My father is a Dutch citizen and was born of Dutch parents in Rotterdam, (i.e. grandfather and grandmother were both Dutch) and although he resides in South Africa did not give up his Dutch citizenship. He is married to a South African women (my mother) and adopted me soon after they were married. Both my father and mother have and travel on Dutch passports. Am I eligible for a Dutch passport?

Comment: Similar: *https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/11159/6*

Comment: The answer to this question depends on several things.  Was your father ever naturalized in South Africa or another country?  If in South Africa was it before or after he married your mother?  When were you born?  When were you adopted?

Comment: No my father was never naturalized in South Africa or any other country. (He remains a Dutch Citizen). I was born in 1958 and I was adopted in 1974. (aged 16).